# Powershell - Restart remote windows server with a check built-in

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to build a powershell script which restarts a remote windows service. This has been working fine so far, but I would like to built in a check system.

So far the service stops and starts again just fine, but seeing as it's running on a production machine we would like an extra check:

```
function setStatusOfService {
    for ($service)
    {
        $serviceinfo3 = Get-Service $service -ComputerName $Computer1

        if ($serviceinfo3.Status -eq 'Running')
        {
            Get-Service -Name $Service1 -ComputerName $Computer1 | Stop-Service
            GetStatusOfService $service -ComputerName $Computer1
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
        }
        else
        {
            Get-Service -Name $Service1 -ComputerName $Computer1 | Start-Service 
            GetStatusOfService $service -ComputerName $Computer1       
            break
        }

    }
    exit
}
```

This works pretty well. But I've tried to built in a way that the function keeps trying to start the service when it fails but to no avail.

The other step I'm rather stuck on is that Powershell sends out an e-mail when it completed the script. After it stops and starts the service again, it checks the status and sends that specific status out:

```
Function getStatusOfService {
    $serviceinfo = Get-Service $service -ComputerName $Computer1
    Write-Host $service is $serviceinfo.Status
    SendEmail
}
```

But what i can't get working so far, is that it only should send out an e-mail when the status is stopped. I've tried multiple options like `Status -eq "stopped"` but it sends out the e-mail anyway.

Can anyone give me some advice on how I can built this in?

Kind regards,

Rick.

Comment: Your for loop seems off. What are you trying to achieve there? A for loop looks like this: For ($i=0; $i -le 10; $i++) . If you are going for a endless loop (which you should not do imho), use while($true).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but checking a service and send a mail when it is stopped should work like this:

```
$service = Get-Service "servicename" -ComputerName "Computer"
if($service.status -eq "Stopped"){
     Send-Mailmessage -to "it@it.com" -from "computer@it.com" -Subject "Stopped Service" -Body "Service $service.name stopped."
}
```

If you want to check this constantly, you could use a scheduled task to run a script multiple times.